# How to remove html select has duplicate data and text name using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listbox

Is there a way to remove or group the duplicate data and text name of select option in jquery? PLEASE CHECK [THIS](http://prntscr.com/g39gpp)

Comment: Please add your HTML code and what you have tried so far (if anything)

Comment: can you show the specific piece of code that's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use below code to remove duplicate options:

Using [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) (to target sibling `option` elements), and [Attribute Equals Selector `[attr='']`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```js
$("#color option").val(function(idx, val) {
  $(this).siblings("[value='"+ val +"']").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class ="select-form" name="color" id="color">
  <option value="">Select Color</option>
  <option value="1">Color 1</option>
  <option value="2">Color 2</option>
  <option value="3">Color 3</option>
  <option value="3">Color 3</option> <!-- will be removed since value is duplicate -->
  <option value="2">Color 2</option> <!-- will be removed since value is duplicate -->
</select>
```

Comment: Question is about removing option has duplicate data and text. Your solution isn't perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are writing the code, but from a high level you could something like along of creating an array that holds every single line of HTML outputed (even duplicates), then create another array and only add unique values to it so there are no duplicates.
IE

```
    var HTML = ["<option>stuff </option>","<option>same stuff </option>","<option> same stuff </option>","<option>different stuff </option>","<option>different stuff </option>","<option>different stuff </option>","<option>different stuff </option>"];
    var uniqueHTML = [];
    $.each(names, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueHTML) === -1) uniqueHTML.push(el);
});
```

This will remove any duplicates and leave you array of unique HTML values, which then you could iterate through as output. Not the most time efficient approach, but without providing any code, here is what I can offer.